# Отладка эндпоинта websocket в Idea

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, отладка

Всем привет.

Проект на java spring.

Есть ли возможность выполнить debug сервиса, метод которого общается с клиентом по websocket, из среды idea?

Почему-то после запуска в debug режиме idea не приземляет на указанный end_point, если метод работает через ws.

На другие end_point сервиса, которые работают по http перехожу свободно.

В чем может быть проблема? Подскажите куда копать...

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у тебя неправильно настроен клиент debug'а и, возможно, удалённая JVM не поднята в режиме debug'а. Для того чтобы дебажить JVM (не только java, а любое приложение для JVM) в IDEA, нужно добавить конфигурацию `Remote`. См. (1) на картинке. После надо будет ввести адрес или ip машины с JVM, на которой крутится твоё приложение (2). Там же (2) вводится порт, к которому ты будешь подключаться, и который должна слушать JVM с твоим приложением. Плюс выбираешь версию JVM, которую хочешь дебажить (3). Для лиги лени ребята из JetBrains (авторы IDEA) добавили параметры командной строки JVM (4), с которыми ты должен запустить удалённую JVM с твоим приложением, чтобы она стартовала в нужном для тебя debug'а режиме.

[image: DebugJVM]

P.S. Также для успешного дебага необходимо, чтобы твоё запущенное (удалённо) приложение не было скомпилированно с опциями оптимизации, т.к. последнее сносит debug-символы из него.